# ASP.NET Rejects Connection from other PC

Tags: asp.net

Well, I've got Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate installed in my development machine and I need to test my Webservice on several devices such as tablets, cellphones and other notebooks. My problem is I've been unable to access the webservice besides from the localmachine.
I've tryed java tunnels, Port forwarders, everything. All of them works as I can access my machine from different ports but still I'm getting the 
Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

How can I bypass this? Do I need a machine with Windows Server to test everything?

Comment: How are you hosting your web service?  If it's the personal development server or IIS express, it ain't going to work from another box.  That's by design.

Comment: Yes, but then how can I test my web service easily or any workaround so I don't have to get a virtual machine with Windows Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click your asp.net project, and go to 'Web'.  Change from Visual Studio Development Server to IIS.  Then you can reach the site from other devices on the network by replacing 'localhost' with your computer name

Comment: good advice here. Also I would add, this  Assumes Computer is registering in DNS. If name fails to be resolved, enter the IP.  eg Http://nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/<use site guff>  incase sitename is not resolved

Comment: I've already ruled that out. Use Local IIS Web Server is selected, with Use IIS Express selected also. I've run out of options.

Comment: don't use IIS express.

Comment: I can't deselect it as It's greyed out. Is it possible to get IIS not express working on windows 7?

Comment: @CristianEduardoLehuedeLyon Installing IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, or Ultimate: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725762.aspx - you may need to enable some features within IIS too.